# Is there a way to search example questions on Area51?

Tags: feature-request, search, area-51, example-questions

I posed an example [question](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/117/quantitative-finance/1324#1324) that had already been covered.  If there were a way to search before I asked a question, or if possible duplicate questions were shown to me as I asked it could eliminate this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching on the home page also searches questions, but it doesn't show it very well right now.  We'll improve this interface in the near future.

Showing duplicate questions is also be a good idea.