# Why is the bicycles proposal shown when searching for phys?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51, search

"physic" is not even mentioned in the description!

And [substring searching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61935/also-search-substrings-in-area-51s-proposal-search)  seems to be partially implemented, since the [Physics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1908/physics?referrer=Ho2q28uHijgN5QfMOt5KEg2) proposal shows up as expected. However, nothing shows up at "physi", so some filtering mechanism seems broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substring searching is not actually implemented, which is why "phys" doesn't return any results.  I think what you're seeing with "physic" matching "physics" is actually [stemming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142509.aspx) - it sees "physics" as a form of the word "physic" and matches both.  You'll see similar results if you search "physical" for the same reason.

Comment: So, is this going to be changed? [Substring searching](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61935/also-search-substrings-in-area-51s-proposal-search) would be really useful, but stemming and the unconditional search through example questions are not so helpful in finding duplicate proposals. Ok, stemming maybe, but not the latter.

Answer (score 4):

The search box searches [proposals *and* questions on proposals](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52018/is-there-a-way-to-search-example-questions-on-area51).  There is an example question on bicycles ["What forces of physics make a bike stay upright?"](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2305/bicycles/5991#5991)

So that's why it's showing up.

Comment: So I guess the search cannot handle the too many result somehow containing "physi" because of e.g. the addition of "physiology" results...